# Ionic run android seems to work, but the app is not launched on the phone, why?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

My phone is on and in debug-mode I have confirmed this with `adb devices -l`.
When I run ionic run android, I get the output below Ionic claims that the application is launched, but nothing happens on the phone. I use a Nexus 5 with android 4.4.4.

```
$ ionic run android
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/cordova/run 
Buildfile: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Development/adt-bundle/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: KvittoScanner
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for KvittoScanner...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for KvittoScanner...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Development/adt-bundle/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: 

    /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop

    -post-build:

    debug:

    -code-gen:
    [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
    [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
    [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
         [echo] Handling aidl files...
         [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling Resources...
         [aapt] Found modified input file
         [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
         [echo] ----------
         [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
    [buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

    -pre-compile:
         [echo] Set jars path to: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

    -compile:
        [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/classes

    -post-compile:

    -obfuscate:

    -dex:
          [dex] input: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
          [dex] input: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
          [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-d889c6bd0911025d0e9120cf57234197.jar <- /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
          [dex] Found modified input file
          [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/classes.dex...
           [dx] Merged dex A (14 defs/28.2KiB) with dex B (206 defs/314.1KiB). Result is 220 defs/415.6KiB. Took 0.3s

    -crunch:
       [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/res
       [crunch] To destination dir: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/res
       [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

    -package-resources:
         [aapt] Found modified input file
         [aapt] Creating full resource package...
         [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
         [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
         [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
         [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
         [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
         [aapt] Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.

    -package:
    [apkbuilder] Found modified input file
    [apkbuilder] Creating KvittoScanner-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

    -post-package:

    -do-debug:
     [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
         [echo] Debug Package: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/KvittoScanner-debug.apk
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop

    -post-build:
         [move] Moving 1 file to /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build
         [move] Moving 1 file to /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build

    debug:

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 5 seconds
    WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device '05f2fdad3444ea60'.
    Using apk: /Users/kristoffer/web/photoApp/platforms/android/ant-build/KvittoScanner-debug-unaligned.apk
    Installing app on device...
    Launching application...
    LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

index.html in the android app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- ngCordova -->
    <script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" class="platform-android platform-cordova platform-webview">
    <!-- 
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon  ion-ios7-arrow-back">
        Back
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!-- 
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the APK file visible in the device? How is the opening (index.html) file coded? Have all the relevant tags added in the head tag of the index.html file? can you show us how your index.html file is coded?

Comment: where can I find the apik file? Updating with index file soon, ionic takes care of opening the right?

Comment: What i meant by APK file is that is the APP that your developing physically visible/installed in the Nexus? You must have given some name(photoAPP) to your APP. is that name visible in your Nexus phone?  Your Index.html file seems to be OK.

Comment: Strange... is device '05f2fdad3444ea60' the correct id of your nexus 5 when you run adb devices -l?

Comment: @frank it doesn't show up in the app-list in the menu unless I manually move the apk-file to the phone and open it.

Comment: @QuickFix, not sure, but if I unplug my phone 05f2fdad3444ea60 dissapear.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren so when you manually move, what does it show when you run the APP? Also why don't you use cordova/phonegap for making builds and running your application? I am not too familiar with the Ionic BUILD process.

Comment: The app is shown as it is if I run it on a webpage on my computer. Cordova and ionic build and run are exactly the same(I have tried both)

Comment: It is a cumbersome process. when you run `adb devices` in `%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools`, did you see your `05f2fdad3444ea60` as `unauthorized` or `device`?

Comment: Did you fix the problem? Because I'm having the same one.

Comment: I also had same problem. I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956031/cordova-run-android-executes-fine-but-android-4-1-2-doesnt-start-the-app) to solve my problem

Comment: is there a step by step guide to test ionic app on android?

Comment: @nabin I experienced the same issue and your link helped me. I gave a bounty on this question, because I do not want to create a duplicate and I needed some help. I'd like to give the bounty to your solution if you post a non link-only one. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Type ionic info and check which Cordova version you have installed. If you have v5.0.0 that now requires a new plugin otherwise all http requests are blocked.

Recently cordova released cordova-android 4.0 with the laster version of the cordova cli. The changes in cordova-android prevent any http request by default. There have already been a few posts about this issue. To fix this, all you have to do is add the cordova-whitelist-plugin. ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist
see ref:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-proccess-changed-and-now-cannot-call-to-api/25103

Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

try disabling the firewall on your machine. it worked for me and I have the same configuration as you do

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem sometime back. The reason for that was my source files in www/ folder didn't had cordova.js included in the index.html. If someone faces this problem, do make sure to add cordova.js in the source files like

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```