# Problems connecting Android device and running adb commands

Tags: android, cordova, adb, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic-framework app, and I have troubles running the command **ionic run android** which runs the apk directly on a connected Android device, it just does nothing, like in this question: [Ionic run android seems to work, but the app is not launched on the phone, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281711/ionic-run-android-seems-to-work-but-the-app-is-not-launched-on-the-phone-why)

So I tried to install the apk with **adb install** and it does nothing too.

The only way to install an apk is to save it directly into the device and install it with packet manager.

Other adb commands like **adb usb** just run and never finnish, doing nothing. The only commands that seems to work is **adb logcat** and **adb devices** which show no problem with my device:

```
$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached 
0123456789ABCDEF       device usb:2-1.5
```

I'm using:

```
Ionic    --version 1.3.20
Cordova  --version 5.0.0 
Phonegap --version 4.2.0-0.24.2
Android device: HTC One S
Android version: 4.1.1 HTC Sense 4+
SO: Ubuntu 14.10 64 bits
```

I have all Android SDKs installed.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to replace the HTC device and its USB cable with a Samsung device and a generic cable. Searching the Internet I found that for some reason adb doesn't work well or at all with HTC.

Plus, I had to constantly kill the adb process with **adb kill-server**, so it could start fresh with every adb command.

**Ionic run android** also uses adb, and it worked fine with the Samsung device as well.

Answer (score 1):

How did you give adb install ?
**adb install** path to apk(Drag and drop apk to command prompt)  and the press enter to start install

Comment: That's what I did, **adb install /path/file.apk**

Comment: adb install [path] worked for me. +1 for the drag and drop to cmd!

Answer (score 0):

This issue may come from your device AND from your USB dongle.

If you are using Samsung, you need to install http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/ and update your device drivers.

I faced that issue with Galaxy S3 & Galaxy S4 and after update with keys and change of USB calbe, it was working as expected.